# Sign of $\cos(x)-2 \cos(3x)$

Tags: real-analysis

How to determine the sign of $\cos(x)-2 \cos(3x)$, $x\in [0,2\pi]$?

Comment: What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write $\cos3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$ then
$$\cos x-8\cos^3x+6\cos x=\cos x(7-8\cos^2x)$$